# Keep only tables containing certain string with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a large dictionary with html files like this one: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1961/0001264931-18-000031.txt
I want to keep only the tables containing the word income tax or Income tax. I use BeautifulSoup to get the tables but am unable to get the tables containing the correct strings. My current approach using in usually works for string but it does not seem to work for BeautifulSoup objects.

```py
for filename, text in tqdm(dictionary.items()):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    for table in tables:
        try:
            if 'income tax' or 'Income tax' in table:
                good = table
            else:
                pass
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: and if you do `if ('income tax' in str(table)) or ('Income tax' in str(table))` ?

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll pass it in answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert your beautifulsoup object to a string and correctly format your if statement :

```py
if ('income tax' in str(table)) or ('Income tax' in str(table)):
```

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1. you should be able to use :contains to filter

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1961/0001264931-18-000031.txt')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
tables = soup.select('table:contains("income tax","Income tax")')
```

Comment: This looks like a really nice solution, but for some reason my Beautiful Soup only updates to version 4.6.0. Do you know how to get the latest version?

Comment: unsure. Perhaps: pip install --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4==4.8.0